# The mypy daemon executable ('dmpy') was not found

Tags: python, mypy

I installed mypy with poetry and after that I installed the mypy extension in vs code, but the message :

The mypy daemon executable ('dmypy') was not found on your PATH. Please install mypy or adjust the mypy.dmypyExecutable setting.

when I run the command 'which mypy', I get the result:

/Users/luicruz/Projects/google-seasonality/.venv/bin/mypy

so the mypy is installed...

It is showing up every hour in the bottom right corner of my Visual Studio Code. How do I fix it?

[image]

I tried following some forum tutorials but it didn't work when I messed with the settings.json in the Visual Studio code, I tried putting a key "mypy.path": "path to mypy" and it still didn't work:

"mypy.path":"/Users/luicruz/Projects/google-seasonality/.venv/bin/mypy",

Answer (score 1):

the error stopped occurring when i closed all visual studio code tabs, apparently it may have been some synchronization error between the poetry library installation and the installation of the mypy extension in vs code, and this makes sense considering that i had more than one vs code tab open...

Answer (score 0):

This extension requires mypy to be installed on your system. To install mypy, run `pip install mypy`. There are other ways to install mypy, such as using pipx or your system's package manager.

By default, this extension relies on having the dmypy executable available on your PATH. This should be the case if you installed mypy globally. To use a different mypy installation, set the `mypy.dmypyExecutable setting`.

Some people prefer to have mypy installed in each project's virtual environment rather than in a global location. To do this, enable `mypy.runUsingActiveInterpreter` (either globally or for a specific workspace).

Answer (score -1):

After I installing Mypy Type Checker Extension, now type error is working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).